# htaccess Redirect php url with 301

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I have a website with url like

```
www.website.com/showproduct.php?p=123456
```

where "123456" is the particular product to show.

With htaccess I rewrite it to

```
www.website.com/product/123456
```

by using

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^product/(.*)/?$ /showproduct.php?p=$1 [L]
```

the problem is that google has stored in cache the old url, so it still access the pages using `www.website.com/showproduct.php?p=123456`.

How can I implement a `301` redirect to `www.website.com/product/123456` ?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can place this redirect just below `RewriteEngine On` line to handle Google cache URL:

```sh
RewriteEngine On

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+showproduct\.php\?p=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /product/%1? [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^product/([\w-]+)/?$ showproduct.php?p=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```